# javascript automatic copy text to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I'm trying to copy content to clipboard without user action but this doesn't work.
is because firefox detect the origin of the action ? (click() function and not user real clic)

https://jsfiddle.net/ukj871dc/

```
<div id='div'>some text</div>

$("<button id='clickme'>clickme</button>").insertAfter( "#div" );
$("<textarea id='temptext'></textarea>").insertAfter( "#clickme" );
$("#temptext").css({"position": "fixed", "bottom": "0px", "left": "0px", "opacity": "0"});

// next one doesn't work
setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById("clickme").click();}, 2000);

$("#clickme").click(function(){
var textToCopy = $('#div').text();
$('#temptext').val(textToCopy);
$('#temptext').select();
document.execCommand('copy');                                     
});
```

It's just for personal interest don't bother long explanation
you could give me links to documentation as well

Comment: Your fiddle works on Chrome and Firefox on my side. (I'm on a Mac)

Comment: For full cross browser support, I believe [zeroclipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) is still the best option, `execCommand` is still not supported in Safari, and only in later versions of the other browsers

Comment: Doen't work on Firefox on windows without clicking manually,  i don't need cross broser solution but i'll test it on chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox pre-41, you need to enable clipboard support manually in the user.js preference file. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_compatibility